# Double-clicking a styled checkbox incorrectly selects text next to it

Tags: html, css

In the below example I have a custom checkbox (the selected image doesn't work because the URL is invalid, but disregard that).

In this CSS, **double-clicking** the checkbox for some reason selects the text that is next to it. This shouldn't happen and I have to fix this behavior. On the first double-click it selects the first word and then an additional part. Does anyone know where this comes from?

```css
.my-checkbox {
       margin-bottom: 40px;
       background: #fff;
}

.my-checkbox__input {
      position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    right: auto;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}

.my-checkbox__label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inherit;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 0.75rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    color: #1b1b1b;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro Web,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.06rem;
    line-height: 1.3;
}

.my-checkbox__label::before {
    content: " ";
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 0.064rem;
    position: absolute;
    height: 1.25rem;
    width: 1.25rem;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #1b1b1b;
}

.my-checkbox__input:checked+[class*=__label]::before {
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 0.75rem auto;
}

.my-checkbox__input:checked+[class*=__label]::before {
    background-image: url('my.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>

<div class="my-checkbox">
    <input class="my-checkbox__input" id="checkbox0" title="Select All" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
    <label class="my-checkbox__label" for="checkbox0"></label>
 </div>
    </td>
    <td>
       Some text in another table column
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>
Regular checkbox:

<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
       <div>
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox0" />
         <label for="checkbox0"></label>
       </div>
     </td>
     <td>
        Some text in another table column
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

In terms of custom-CSS checkboxes using `label` and `::before`/`::after`, I see that this example doesn't have this problem, but mine does:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_checkbox

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. Double clicking for me doesn't select the text. (I am on firefox on sway on nixos so not the most common environment but still)

Comment: I updated the OP with a screenshot. Happening on BOTH Edge and Chrome for me. (Sorry I don't have Firefox)

Comment: Just tested in a chromium based browser and I can confirm that the issue occurs there

Comment: After a little bit of experimentation with clicking rapidly on firefox and vivaldi I have noticed that vivaldi definitely tends to select stuff that firefox doesn't when clicking in the same areas. I wonder if this is documented anywhere

Comment: Remove the table from the equation and you'll see the problem

Comment: Even if there's no table, and just a label next to it, it still shouldn't select any text. Regular checkboxes don't. "Remove the table from the equation and you'll see the problem" doesn't help me with anything, nor is it a sufficient StackOverflow answer.

Comment: @j08691 comment is useful as it removes some of the spurious complexity. We can remove even more. input has nothing to do with the problem so remove it. Try using a couple of spans next to each other and you get the same problem. e.g. <span style="display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: solid 1px black;"></span><span>Some text<span>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same sort of problem can be seen in even simpler cases, for example two adjacent spans. If there is no text in the first one then the first word in the second one is selected on a double click. [This is on Windows 10 Edge/Chrome].

Taking the example given in the question, we can switch off selection in the label (`user-select: none;`) and it will not 'move on' to select the first word in the next element.

```css
.my-checkbox {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background: #fff;
}

.my-checkbox__input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
  right: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

.my-checkbox__label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 0.75rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  color: #1b1b1b;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro Web, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.06rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  user-select: none;
}

.my-checkbox__label::before {
  content: " ";
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top: 0.064rem;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1.25rem;
  width: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #1b1b1b;
}

.my-checkbox__input:checked+[class*=__label]::before {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 0.75rem auto;
}

.my-checkbox__input:checked+[class*=__label]::before {
  background-image: url('my.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>

      <div class="my-checkbox">
        <input class="my-checkbox__input" id="checkbox0" title="Select All" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
        <label class="my-checkbox__label" for="checkbox0"></label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      Some text in another table column
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/> Regular checkbox:

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox0" />
        <label for="checkbox0"></label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      Some text in another table column
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question on why that select behaviour is happening, while I couldn't find any documentation on this behaviour / bug, I did notice that it only happened when using `position: absolute;` on `.my-checkbox__label::before`. If you switch that to `position: relative`, text won't be selected in the other table data cell.

If you didn't want to update it's `position` and just wanted to disable that behaviour, you can add `user-select: none` to the parent element, like so: `<div class="my-checkbox" style="user-select: none;">` to disable user-select behaviour on child elements.

As for making your checkbox actually function like an input, that isn't your question so I'll leave my answer there. But here is a url for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

```css
.my-checkbox {
    /*margin-bottom: 40px;*/
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #fff;
}

.my-checkbox__input {
      position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    right: auto;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}

.my-checkbox__label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inherit;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 0.75rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    color: #1b1b1b;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro Web,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.06rem;
    line-height: 1.3;
    
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

.my-checkbox__label::before {
    content: " ";
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 0.064rem;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    
    height: 1.25rem;
    width: 1.25rem;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #1b1b1b;
}

.my-checkbox__input:checked+[class*=__label]::before {
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 0.75rem auto;
}

.my-checkbox__input:checked+[class*=__label]::before {
    background-image: url('my.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="my-checkbox">
          <input class="my-checkbox__input" id="checkbox0" title="Select All" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
          <label class="my-checkbox__label" for="checkbox0"></label>
       </div>
    </td>
    <td>
       Some text in another table column
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```